What does this mean if a person is about to take a drug test - "Applicant may be tested for illegal drugs including but not limited to marijuana"?
Could someone elaborate the exact meaning of the following:
The applicant may be tested for illegal drugs, including but not limited to marijuana.

Please amend your title, which say legal, to make it consistent with the body text.

I have edited the title.

It means in addition to the test for marijuana, the applicant will be tested also for other illegal drugs.
[The] applicant may be tested for illegal drugs including (marijuana) but not limited to marijuana.
The first mention of the drug has been elided as it is understood.
Please see usage examples.
